# How can javascript find which buttons were pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm am trying to write a vote system, and don't want to repeat the same code twice, depending on whether the user presses vote up or vote down. Therefore I would like the same function to run, and javascript to determine which button was pressed. But for some reason, no matter which button I press, it always add +1 to votes, the first time you press it, and the second time you press it just says NaN in the console. This is the HTML:

```
        <li><input type ="button" value="Vote up!" onclick='vote()' id="vote"></li>
        <li><input type ="button" value="Vote Down!" onclick='vote()' id="vote"></li>
```

and this is the the javascript:

```
function vote(){
    var votes = document.getElementById('votes').innerHTML;
    var snippetID = document.getElementById('snippetID').innerHTML;

if (document.getElementById('vote').value = 'Vote up!') {
    votes = parseInt(votes + 1);
}
else if (document.getElementById('vote').value = 'Vote down!') {
    votes = parseInt(votes - 1);
};

console.log(votes);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "voteUp",
    data: "votes="+votes+"&snippetID="+snippetID,
    success: function(data) {
        document.getElementById('votes').innerHTML = ''
        document.getElementById('votes').innerHTML = data;
    }
});
}
```

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context

Comment: Create two separate functions – one for up vote and one for down vote.

Comment: iD CANNOT BE DUPLICATED

Comment: Id's must be unique and try to avoid inline javascript and all these `getelementById` could be replaced by some `this` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign different IDs to the buttons.

```
<li><input type ="button" value="Vote up!" class="vote" id="vote_up"></li>
<li><input type ="button" value="Vote Down!"class="vote" id="vote_down"></li>
```

Then you do something like this:

```
$('.vote').click(function() {
    var action = $(this).attr('id');
    if(action === 'vote_up')
    {
        //put vote up logic here
    }
    elseif( action === 'vote_down')
    {
        //put vote down logic here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure

**Javascript**

```
function vote(x){
    var votes = document.getElementById('votes').innerHTML;
    var snippetID = document.getElementById('snippetID').innerHTML;

if (x = 'Vote up!') {
    votes = parseInt(votes + 1);
}
else if (x = 'Vote down!') {
    votes = parseInt(votes - 1);
};

console.log(votes);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "voteUp",
    data: "votes="+votes+"&snippetID="+snippetID,
    success: function(data) {
        document.getElementById('votes').innerHTML = ''
        document.getElementById('votes').innerHTML = data;
    }
});
}
```

**Html**

Answer (score 0):

Other than fixing your `id`s so they are unique on the page, the entire system of javascript is set up to easily find what element set off the event.

There are two ways you can enable this. The closest to what you have on your markup so far would be to edit your element so that it has this attribute:

```
onclick="vote(this)"
```

The other, if you are using jQuery, would be to not include the `onclick`, and wire the event up like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li input[type="button"]').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            var $self = $(this); // Long term, you'll need to recognize that the "this" can be different than the "this" in the line above. In this instance, they are the same element.
            var direction = $self.attr('value');

            if (direction.toUpper() === 'VOTE UP') {
                // Increment vote count.
            }
            else {
                // Decrement vote.
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Inline javascript shouldn't be provided as an option in that case nor in most other cases. There a POJS and jQuery solutions to avoid this, and as the OP is already using jQuery to do some AJAX I think you should only leave your second solution.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, `id` needs to be unique. Otherwise, you can the `name` attribute for that.
In your case, however, you do not need ids or names.

You can simply do:

```
<li><input type ="button" value="Vote up!" onclick='vote(+1)'></li>
<li><input type ="button" value="Vote Down!" onclick='vote(-1)'></li>
```

And then in your JS:

```
function vote(value) {
    var nodeVotes = document.getElementById('votes');
    var snippetID = document.getElementById('snippetID').innerHTML;

    var votes = +nodeVotes.innerHTML + value;

    console.log(votes);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "voteUp",
      data: "votes="+votes+"&snippetID="+snippetID,
      success: function(data) {
        nodeVotes.innerHTML = data;
      }
    });
}
```

Notice that the `+` in `vote(+1)` in the HTML is redundant, but IMVHO makes it more clear in this context (reading the code is "vote plus one").